# is there a way to allow only one user to access a Google spreadsheet that is published as a web page

Tags: google-sheets

i have a spreadsheet that is published as a web page.

can i share this to a single user ?

my account is a Google application account and when i publish a spreadsheet, all users in my company can access it.

is there any way to block this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no way to achieve this.

you can use other methods like embedding this in web pages or Google site pages